# Not able to click (Sometimes) categories(Y-axis) of gantt chart after updating series data results

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Expected behavior :

After chart data is updated , Categories (Y-axis) can be clicked and chart expands those clicked category child elements .

Actual behavior :

After chart data is updated , issues as below

Click on categories sometimes doesn't work at all.

Can be clicked but responds after many seconds.

On responding to click the height of the chart is kept constant hence all the child elements wraps itself inside the previous allocated div
Live demo with steps to reproduce

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxtt87

Wait for 3 seconds so that chart gets updated
Click on multiple Y axis categories
Collapse all and try to expand

P.S : IF there is an error in console please update anything in app.component.html file , error rectifies automatically (seems issue with stack blitz)

Comment: Below code fixed your stack blitz issue:



this.chartGantt.series[1]['data'][1].end = Date.UTC(this.today.getFullYear(), this.today.getMonth(), this.today.getDate(), 24);
        this.chartGantt.series[1]['data'][0].end = Date.UTC(this.today.getFullYear(), this.today.getMonth(), this.today.getDate(), 24);
        this.chartGantt.series[0]['keys'] = true;
        this.chartGantt.series[1]['keys'] = true;
        this.chartGantt.series[2]['keys'] = true;
        this.dataUpdated = true;
        this.oneToOneFlag = true;

Comment: @sivakumar Sorry about that , It didn't clear the issue . Irrespective of that about the actual issue in high chart i have raised , Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is already reported as a bug on Highcharts GitHub:

- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11739

Please follow this thread on GitHub. There should be Gantt core developer answer soon.